# PHP Session not updated

Tags: php, session, background, chat

I'm building a chat in php/ajax. In order to detect users timeout, I wrote a background php script which disconnects the user if there is no activity for 5 seconds.

The problem is, the variable in the sessions are not updated...

Here is my chat.php where all the ajax queries are performed (at least 1 per second and per client) :

```
<?php
session_save_path("sessions");
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_request'] = time();
```

Here is how I launch the background script from this chat.php :

```
exec('php user_manager.php ' . session_id() . ' > /tmp/output &');
```

And here is my loop to check if the user is still here (this is the background process) :

```
<?php
session_save_path("sessions");
session_id($argv[1]);
session_start();
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

echo "background task starting on user " . $_SESSION['user'] . PHP_EOL;

$lastrequest = $_SESSION["last_request"];

while(time() - intval($lastrequest) < 5) { //5 seconds
    echo "last_request : " . $lastrequest . PHP_EOL;
    $lastrequest = $_SESSION["last_request"];
    sleep(1);
}

echo "disconnecting user !" . PHP_EOL;
```

And as you can see, the last_request session variable is never updated :

```
# cat /tmp/output
background task starting on user test
last_request : 1493120020
last_request : 1493120020
last_request : 1493120020
last_request : 1493120020
last_request : 1493120020
disconnecting user !
```

I don't understand why and it's driving me crazy... Please help !

Comment: The `$_SESSION` war is only filled once, when you call the script. If someone else changes a session var, while you execute the script, this change wont get populated to your current script

Comment: @Philipp this is the same user who calls the same script, so he might have the same session

Comment: When you open a session in a script, it is blocked so you cannot have 2 scripts / requests access the same session at the same time. Once the session is opened, the other request will have to wait until the the first script is finished.

Comment: @jeroen but the background process doesn't write in session... It just reads it ! Otherwise, how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: It opens the session so it locks it. You could try closing the session after you read the variable and then open it again when you want to read it again.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks @jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_SESSION array is initiated at the session_start, but after it won't be modified by the user chat script.
You should use a file per session where the chat.php write the last access time. The background process have to read this file in the while block.

Chat script:

```
<?php
session_save_path("sessions");
session_start();
file_put_contents('access_' . session_id() . '.txt', time());
```

Background process:

```
<?php
session_save_path("sessions");
session_id($argv[1]);
session_start();
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

echo "background task starting on user " . $_SESSION['user'] . PHP_EOL;

$lastrequest = file_get_contents('access_' . session_id() . '.txt');

while(time() - intval($lastrequest) < 5) { //5 seconds
    echo "last_request : " . $lastrequest . PHP_EOL;
    $lastrequest = file_get_contents('access_' . session_id() . '.txt');
    sleep(1);
}

echo "disconnecting user !" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, even if it's not what I did, I know it will work ! I preferred the way @jeroen told me (by closing and reopening the session), because I don't have to manage any file. But your answer is the only, and I know it's a good one so I mark it as correct ;)

Comment: Ok, I understand why better for you. And thank you! :)